# i want to convert input string into array using laravel "request" API

Tags: php, laravel

i want to convert input field data into array via using laravel request API

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class someclass{
function $function( request $request)
{
// input text = car-bus-truck
$GetIncomingFeildInArray = expolde('-', $request->name(array_search('en', $request->lang)));  

print_r($GetIncomingFeildInArray);

//output should be like this , array( [0]=>'car', [1]=>'bus', [2]=> 'truck')

}
}
?>
```

Comment: Request usually included key-value pair payload (e.g) 
`
{
    "name": "john doe",
    "age" : 30,
    "type": "car-bus-truck"
}
`
Based on type, you can explode.

Comment: `function $function` looks like a typo.  `request $request` looks like another typo, `Request` is capitalised.  `expolde()` is typo number 3.  Is this your real code?

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED ----> Thank you all :)

```
<?php
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    
    class someclass{
    function $function( request $request)
    {
    // input text = car-bus-truck
    $GetIncomingFeildInArray = explode('-', $request->input('text'));  
           print_r($GetIncomingFeildInArray);
    
    //output should be like this , array( [0]=>'car', [1]=>'bus', [2]=> 'truck')
    
    }
    }
    ?>
```